# Eclipse issue with java 9 and maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-platform-module-system, module-path

I installed **Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a) Build id: 20171005-1200** supporting Java 9.

With suggested configuratio on eclipse.ini

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin\javaw.exe
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

I have developed by java 9 (java 9 modularity) [code](https://github.com/venergiac/my-module-prj) project to test dependency injection as pure Java prject from eclipse, but when I have integrated Maven running my from eclipse I get systematically the following error

> Error occurred during initialization of boot
>   layerjava.lang.module.FindException: Module com.my.module.hello.test
>   not found

the only solution was to add on VM arguments

```
--module-path target/classes;../my-module-api/target/classes;../my-module-it/target/classes --module com.my.module.hello.test/com.my.module.hello.Reflection
```

[image]

Indeed if add to Vm arguments the verbose parameter I can see during loading

> ... [0.694s][info][class,load] java.lang.NamedPackage source:
>   jrt:/java.base [0.697s][info][class,load] com.my.module.hello.MyHello
>   source:
>   file:/C:/Users/212442540/workspace-training/my-module-prj/my-module/target/classes/
>   [0.698s][info][class,load]
>   java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor$$Lambda$24/2114889273 source:
>   java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor ...

when I remove the "--module-path" parameter this line disappear.

Notice: Eclipse is able to work correctly during the compilation or editing. See the completition and so on ..

[image]

I have added modpath dependencies also to my project

### Forcing dependencies on project config

I added the dependencies manually on the project config
[image]

So it seems that Eclipse is able to compile java 9 modules, but it is not able to run module if integrated with maven.

**Forcing dependencies on Configratin Run**
I have also added the dependencies manually
[image]
**figure 1**

but eclipse continues to remove them.

Before:

[image: manually]

**figure 2**

After run eclipse restores:

[image: after save]
**figure 3**

**It seems that eclipse reset systematically the configuration if integrated with maven.**

Comment: isn't that code a demo of module functionality - is it even expected to work without those parameters?

Comment: The java command should be java --module-path target/classes;../my-module-api/target/classes;../my-module-it/target/classes --module com.my.module.hello.test/com.my.module.hello.Reflection but I'm expecting eclipse do this work for me

Comment: have you went through any eclipse instructions to set them up, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44403070/how-do-i-add-modules-to-the-eclipse-oxygen-module-path-for-a-project)?

Comment: yes done ..tx ..-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin\javaw.exe
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM

Comment: The recommended way is to use _Dependencies_ only without _VM arguments_. If the _my-module_ project is a Java 9 module, it must be on the modulepath, not on the classpath.

Comment: @hwolegee yes it is

Comment: have you checked if the problem is with eclipse-maven integration? does your setup work without maven?

Comment: yes I think so. It works with "pure" maven and "pure" java, but not from eclipse. Also eclipse is able to compile correctly but during Run continues to remove modules from my "Run Configuration"

Comment: Your run configuration contains conflicting settings: your _VM arguments_ are in conflict with the main class and _Dependencies_.

Comment: @venergiac what I meant to ask is if your setup works from eclipse but without maven, so if the problem might be in maven-eclipse integration.

Comment: @eis : yes before Maven it worked now no.

Comment: @venergiac Here is my video how to create a Java 9 module application with Eclipse Oxygen.1a (without Maven):  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wI3VC1lhbK8

Comment: @howlegr: removed Run configuration, cleaned project, remove allcm arguments restarted eclipse figure 2 vs figure 3

Comment: @venergiac add that detail into the question - its important information. The main point of the question should then be eclipse-maven -integration regarding java 9 modules.

Comment: @eis done tx I added more info

Comment: @howlegr: yes tx it works also for me without maven

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem, it looks like a bug of [M2Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/).

[<s>Please report it to Eclipse</s>](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=m2e&component=jdt&short_desc=Unable%20to%20launch%20Java%209%20module%20application&comment=See%20https://stackoverflow.com/q/47109949/6505250). [Bug 526838 - *Eclipse wrong Module dependencies on Run configuration when integrated with maven*](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526838)

As **workaround** use an ***External Tool Configuration*** instead of an Java application run configuration:

1. ***Run > External Tool > External Tool Configurations...***
2. Select ***Program*** and click the ***New launch configuration*** icon in the in the upper left corner
3. Enter the following values:
    
   Location:  `C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`
    
   Working Directory: `${workspace_loc:/my-module}`
    
   Arguments:

   ```
   /C java
   -p target/classes;../my-module-api/target/classes;../my-module-it/target/classes
   -m com.my.module.hello.test/com.my.module.hello.Reflection
   ```
4. Click ***Run***

Comment: @venergiac Thanks for reporting it. I added the link to the bug in my answer.

Comment: @giusy Yes, I guess so, because manually inserted classpath/modulepath entries have disappeared when I reopen the run configuration. But I'm not sure if it is a m2e or a JDK bug.